# Plesk git for multiple domains

Tags: plesk, git

I have two websites on plesk, let's call them
`main.com` and `test.main.com`
I want to create one central git repo hosted on my server.
Then I want split it into two branches, `main` and `dev`.
A folder of `main.com` should always pull the changes from `main` and on `test.main.com` a folder should pull changes from `dev`.
[image]
I managed to get one half of it working, but don't know how to get the second half working for the same repo.
The problem is: In plesk it seems you can only create a git repo for one website, not for two. I thought this is no problem, but I get errors when trying to connect to a git repo from another website.

Does someone know a good solution how to have just one git and deploy two different branches to two different folders automatically?

Comment: Do you have command line access to your sites?   If it were me I would just do the git stuff on the command line.   I'd use a `cron` job if I needed to keep it up to date automatically on a schedule.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, I don't have command line access

Comment: having this issue too. did you check with plesk support?

Comment: @squarecandy no, I didn't

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Plesk Obsidian. When creating a second domain with same GIT repo, I received a message like this:

fatal: destination path '/var/www/vhosts/[YOUR_ABO]/git/memberportal.git' already exists and is not an empty directory.

One has to assign a unique repository name for each domain, even though they might use the same repoistory url:

[image]